# absolute movement of 3D part using matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, 3d, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to implement transformations of 3D parts in relative and absolute co-ordinate systems. I was able to do this for relative movement - aka movement of parts in local co-ordinate systems but failing to correctly implement in absolute (global / model co-ordinate systems).

terminologies used - 
1. 3D parts - Any geometry (combination of geometries) drawn in 3 dimensions. I am using parts created in CATIA.
2. Local (relative) co-ordinate systems - Axis system for part
3. Global (absolute) co-ordinate systems - Axis system for the parent of the part.
4. Assembly - parts connected with each other as paret-child. typical tree structure.
These definitions are inline with my usage and understandings.
https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/127422-Local-and-global-coordinate-system

My inputs -

1. Matrix - I have 4X4 matrix defined for each part in an assembly. This defines the transfomration matrix with Rotation, Translation and scale component applied to it. [Transformation matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4UlH.png)
   Its column matrix with variable at 1-10 positions for rotation, 12,13,14 (right bottom) are for translation.
2. Movements - 
   I receive the part movement as a vector of x,y,z values in absolute or relative units.
   Or change in rotation around X, Y or Z axis in degrees.

What have I tried -

I follow bellow steps to convert the input to apply on the matrix. I have to always convert the absolute change to relative change as I can only modify the matrix of leaf node (which will always be in local coordinate system).
here are step by step operations I am using - 
[Steps for new matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcLcm.png)

Step 1- Part in LCS. WCS - World coordinate system; LCS - Local Co-ordinate system
Step 2 - Negate the rotation in LCS. back up the rotation.
Step 3 - move the part to WCS.
Step 4 - Move the part with desired delta in WCS.
Step 5 - Move the part back to LCS
Step 6 - Rotate the back again with rotation saved in Step 1.

Dummy code as below - Its in Typescript, but any other language is fine for me. I am more interested in the matrix computations.

```
//// STEP 1//////

    let absVals = Matrix 4;

    /*This is accumulation of all matrices from child to parent. I take all the matrices starting from Child to the root parent and append with matrix multiplication.*/
    let localVals = Matrix4 on the child node. In our case the the box shown in image;
    let localRotation: .Matrix4 = new Matrix4(localVals);
    localRotation.setTranslation(0, 0, 0); // only local rotation matrix

    //// STEP 2//////

    let localTranslation = localVals.multiplyMatrix(localRotation.inverse()); // only local translation. Step 2 achived.

    //// STEP 3//////

    let localInGlobalSpace = localTranslation.multiplyMatrix(res); // move the part in WCS. Step 3 achieved.

    let xDelta = this.xMovement;
    let yDelta = this.yMovement;
    let zDelta = this.zMovement;
    let newPos = new Matrix4();
    newPos.setTranslation(new .Vector3(xDelta, yDelta, zDelta));
    // Similarly rotations should be handled but can skipped for first step

    //// STEP 4//////

    let movedLocalInGlobalSpace = localInGlobalSpace.multiplyMatrix(newPos); // Step 4 achived.

    //// STEP 5//////

    let localBackInLocalSpace = movedLocalInGlobalSpace.multiplyMatrix(absVals.inverse()); // Step 5 achived.

    //// STEP 6//////

    let localBackInLocalSpaceWithRotation = localBackInLocalSpace.multiplyMatrix(localRotation); // Step 6 achived.
```

I need help to understand if I am performing the steps correctly in my algorithm.
I have tried to provide as much information as possible. let me know if the post has become hard to understand. Let me know your views.

Comment: What makes you think your algorithm isn't correct?  Are you seeing an error when you run the code?

Comment: The result of the movement are not correct. I cross verify this with another application which has similar function. I am sure that the matrix output after my algorithm is not giving me correct numbers. But I am not able to understand the mistakes I am doing with my computations.

Comment: To clarify, what results did you see?  And what results did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is more about mathematical transformation than code:

Every transformation can be subdivided in one simple translation and three rotations (along each axis). We will consider only 1 translation and 1 rotation for now.

When you apply your rotation you have to be sure that the center of the rotation is the origin, ie 0,0,0.

Example:
If we have a shape defined by four points P1, P2, P3, P4 and we want to apply a rotation (Matrix M) around P1 and a translation (Vector V).

1. You have to translate every points so P1 become the origin.
2. Apply the matrix M "on the left"
3. Retranslate the points so P1 go to its previous place
4. Apply the translation vector

[image: Formula1]

Of course if the center of your rotation is something else, like Pc it will be:

[image: Formula1]

If you want to negate a previous rotation (Matrix M1), and apply a new rotation (Matrix M2), then just consider that:

[image: Formula2]

Regarding your code:

Be carreful. In most language/libraries:

```
C = A.mulityplymatrix(B)
```

Means

[image: Formula2]

Which can be different from:

[image: Formula3]

Applying the translation first and then the rotation will give you something totally different from rotation first then translation.